# PHP code for variable numbers of modules in a single module position

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, joomla3.0

I am creating a Joomla 3.8 template from scratch using Bootstrap 4.0. At the same time I am teaching myself both Bootstrap 4.0 and PHP as I go along, so please bear with me.

Under the main component area I have a full-width position which I have called 'feature_bottom'. At the moment, I have two modules assigned to that position. On a wide desktop screen they are stacked vertically, each full width, but I want them to be side-by-side until the smaller device break points. On another menu item there might be three or four modules in that position, so hard-coding the column width for the modules doesn't work.

In my index.php I have this code in the body:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('featurebottom')) : ?>                          
  <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
        <div id="featurebottom" class="<?php echo $featurebottom_width; ?> featurebottom">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="featurebottom" style="xhtml"/>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I can't work out is how and where to tell the template that on medium plus screens if there are two modules in the feature_bottom position then they should be side-by-side with col-md-6 each, if there are three modules they are side-by-side with col-md-4 each, four modules col-md-3 each and so on, up to twelve modules spread over three rows of col-md-4 each.

I have tried this code above the head tag (only up to 4 modules for testing purposes):

```
<?php if ($featurebottom == 2) {
    $featurebottom_width = "col-md-6";
} elseif ($featurebottom == 3) {
    $featurebottom_width = "col-md-4";
} elseif ($featurebottom == 4) {
    $featurebottom_width = "col-md-3";
} else {
    $featurebottom_width = "col-md-12";
}
?>
```

... but nothing happens. The two modules are still stacked above each other.

What am I doing wrong?

The template can be viewed here: [https://www.vanillasponge.co.uk](https://www.vanillasponge.co.uk/)

**Update: 27.02.18**

If I edit the page manually via a browser's Web Developer > Inspector and add the class 'col-md' after 'moduletable' (for each instance) I can get exactly the effect I want (see image).

[Screenshot of manually adjusted modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k30K.jpg)

If I add " col-md" as a Module Class Suffix in the Joomla module Advanced Tab then it also (sort of) works, but a) it double indents the main content underneath the module title, and b) I don't want to have to do this manually, mainly because my somewhat less techy clients may have to use a version of this module in the future when their current Joomla templates are updated by me in the next 18 months or so in order to work with Bootstrap 4. I can't guarantee that they would remember to add a module class suffix.

Comment: I don't know Joomla but looking at your template I can see `$feature_bottom` is always 1 (presumably it is counting the module rather than the elements inside the module). The `col-md-?` class is being applied to an outer DIV, not to each element inside the module. I am guessing you need to make your class changes inside of the `feature_bottom` module instead of where you have them now.

Comment: Thank you. So now I need to work out how to count the elements in the module... or scrap that idea and have four separate module positions and use the countModules function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer (with thanks to the [jquery website](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). All it takes is a tiny jquery script  added to the very bottom of my index.php file, just before the closing body tag (plus opening and closing script tags, which don't show here:

```
<script>
$( ".feature-bottom > div" ).addClass( "col-md" );
</script>
```

What this means, for those who know as little about Jquery as me, is:

1. *.feature-bottom* is the class of the parent div,
2. *> div* means child divs of the parent, and
3. *.addClass* adds a predefined css class to those children. It is possible to add more than one class inside the double quotes, each separated with a space, just as you would in html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close, see if this works for you?

**Count the number of module items in featurebottom**

The Joomla method for this logic is `countModules`
https://docs.joomla.org/Counting_modules_in_a_given_module_position

```
<?php if($this->countModules('featurebottom') == 2){
    $featurebottom_items = "two";
} elseif ($this->countModules('featurebottom') == 3) {
    $featurebottom_items = "three";
} elseif ($this->countModules('featurebottom') == 4) {
    $featurebottom_items = "four";
} else {
    $featurebottom_items = "one";
}
?>
```

**Apply the class from above to `#featurebottom`**

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('featurebottom')) : ?>                          
  <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
        <div id="featurebottom" class="<?php echo $featurebottom_items; ?> featurebottom">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="featurebottom" style="xhtml"/>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Add a class to your modules**

For each of the modules which will have output in featurebottom, go to module > advanced > module class suffix and add
' featurebottom_item' (no quotation marks, but with a leading space)

**CSS to style the width of your modules**

```
#featurebottom .featurebottom_item{
width:100%;
position: relative;   /* replicate Bootstap column styling */
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
} 

 @media (min-width: 992px){
 #featurebottom.one .featurebottom_item{
 width:100%;
 }

 #featurebottom.two .featurebottom_item{
 width:50%;
 float:left;
 }

 #featurebottom.three .featurebottom_item{
 width:33%;
 float:left;
 }

 #featurebottom.four .featurebottom_item{
 width:25%;
 float:left;
 }
 }
```

You'll probably have to play with paddings and margins in the CSS, and you may even need to add rules like `display:inline-block;`, and my php code is untested. You are so close though that I think you'll be able to take it from here.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, David. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I did try something like that before but, as Johna says above, it's counting the outer div which will always be =1 (or 0) and I need to somehow count the individual elements that are nesting inside the module. Your solution works for separate module positions and I have indeed achieved this with the featuretop1/2/3/4 modules which I have added to the template since posting this question.

Comment: yes @Gillian, i just realised this won't quite work for you too, stay tuned ;)